# Rails show latest entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a working Rails application on version 2.3.5 - I am using many to many model relations and have got almost everything working.

What I would like to do is on my new kase page show the most recent kase job ref at the top.

So for example, if I created a new kase with a job ref of "001", if I then went to create a new kase it would show at the top "Your previous kases reference was 001".

I have the field of jobref in the new kase form, so I am trying to workout what I need to do to output only the last jobref.

If that makes sense!

Thanks,

Danny

EDIT: kase model.

```
class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_latest
      find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 5)
  end

  belongs_to :company # foreign key: company_id
  belongs_to :person # foreign key in join table

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :avatar

  # SEARCH FACILITY
  def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['jobno LIKE ? OR casesubject LIKE ? OR transport LIKE ? OR goods LIKE ? OR comments LIKE ? OR invoicenumber LIKE ? OR netamount LIKE ? OR clientref LIKE ? OR kase_status LIKE ? OR lyingatlocationaddresscity LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition, search_condition])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Kase.first(:order => 'id DESC')`

Or if you have a `created_at` column:

`Kase.first(:order => 'created_at DESC')`

There are many different ways to get what you want, and most depend on how your model is defined.

Edit:

Model:

```
def self.most_recent
  first(:order => 'id DESC') # or whatever query you need to get the most recent
end
```

View:

```
<% if Kase.most_recent %>
  <p>Your previous kases reference was <%= Kase.most_recent.jobref %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would I display by adding this code to only the new.html.erb, or would it have to go in the kase model?

I have added my kase model to my question above.